# How to change the contents of the container after submit modal?

Tags: flutter, dart, modal-dialog

Full code here:
https://pastebin.com/3Nt3Qr0E

App preview and result that I want:
[image]

maybe the code would be like this:

```
Container(
   width: 180.0,
   height: 150.0,
   color: Colors.grey[100],
   child: data == null ? Icon(Icons.touch_app) : Image.memory(data),
),
```

but when I try to use it, still an error. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = await Navigator.of(context).push(any route);
// when you pop the screen return a desired value while popping from modal
```

or

```
await Navigator.of(context).push(any route);
///await till the modal gets popped and get the updated data
setState((){
 data = getUpdatedData();
})
```